# A JavaScript function that modifies nested arrays and converts currencies

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, nested

I'm trying to write a flexible function which reacts differently to different inputs, taking three arguments.

- If the first argument is "add" then the second is an array which contains a currency and an exchange rate (to the dollar), if the item is successfully added it should return the number of added items.
- If the first argument is "convert" then the second is an array which contains the currency and the amount that it has to be converted and the third argument will be the currency that we want to convert the money to.
- If the currency is not present or any of the arguments is missing it should return an error message: "invalid data provided!".
- If the currency is already present it should return "invalid data provided!"
- Otherwise it should return the result of the conversion.

```
var currenciesDB = [];     //First I created the array to store the arrays with each currency and the conversion rate

function dynamicConverter(string, array, currency) {
    var one = undefined;
    if (string == "add") {            //This is the first part, to add currencies to the  array, the one that I'm having problems with.
        function toFindIdx(arrayIdx) { // I write this function to check later with the .findIndex method in order to check if the currency is already in the array
            return value = string;
        }
        return currenciesDB.findIndex(toFindIdx);
    } else if (string == "convert") {         //This is the second part, the converter, but I believe this works pretty well. 
        if (string == undefined || array == undefined || currency == undefined) {
         return "invalid data provided!";
        }
        var currentRate = currenciesDB[currency];
        var desiredRate = currenciesDB[array[1]];
        var USDAmount = array[2] * currentRate;
        var convertedAmount = USDAmount / desiredRate;
        return convertedAmount;
    }
}
```

I believe that the conversion is right, but the first part, I don't have it that much clear, not sure how to check if an array is already inside an array, debugging it, returns for example if we were to try

```
dynamicConverter('add', ['euro', 1.2]);
```

I get that array = 'euro',when it should equal the array ['euro', 1.2].

Comment: Maybe I ask why you want to do this with a single function instead of e.g. a `class` with two methods?

Comment: Don't put `[]` around `array` in the parameter list. That destructures the argument, and sets `array` to the first element of the array.

Comment: Well, I'm  starting to study programming and I haven't got to classes yet. But I'll study that next thanks! Also thanks Barmar, I just change it.

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator; `==` and `===` are equality operators. The `toFindIdx` doesn't make any sense to pass to `findIndex`, whose argument is a function that takes three arguments; the current element in the array, the index of that element, and the array. Your function takes one argument, which would map to the current element, but it is thrown away and you return the result of setting `value` to `string`, which doesn't help much. I'd think you'd want `function toFindIdx(value) { return value === string; }`.